# Why I don't see all elements in multidimensionnel array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I create an multidimensionnal array in php. 
I want to get all questions designation. 
When I try to watch my data, I don't get all questions...

```html
<?php

$questions = array(
 'question' => array(
  'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous pouvoir contrôler votre bateau ?',
  'info' => '',
  'Packs' => array(
   'PackMini' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack contrôle Basique', 
    'c' => array(
     'b7' => '1',
     'b9' => '1'
    ), 
    'm' => array(
     'b7' => '1',
     'b9' => '1'
    ) 
   ),
   'PackTotal' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack contrôle Complet', 
    '50' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b9' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b9' => '2'
     ) 
    ),
    '55' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b9' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b9' => '2'
     ) 
    ),
    '60' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b9' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b9' => '4'
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
 ),
 'question' => array(
  'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous contrôler les lumières?',
  'info' => '',
  'Packs' => array(
   'PackMini' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack lumière basique', 
    'c' => array(
     'bE' => '2'
    ), 
    'm' => array(
     'bE' => '2'
    ) 
   ),
   'PackTotal' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack lumière Complet Intérieur & Exterieur', 
    '35' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '8'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '5'
     ) 
    ),
    '40' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '9'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '6'
     ) 
    ),
    '45' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '11'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '7'
     ) 
    ),
    '50' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '12'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '8'
     ) 
    ),
    '55' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '14'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '9'
     ) 
    ),
    '60' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'bE' => '15'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'bE' => '10'
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
 ),
 'question' => array(
  'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous plus de confort à bord?',
  'info' => 'Mesure de tempêratires, humidité',
  'Packs' => array(
   'PackMini' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack mesure basique', 
    'c' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ), 
    'm' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ) 
   ),
   'PackTotal' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack mesure Complet', 
    '35' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ) 
    ),
    '40' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '5'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ) 
    ),
    '45' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '5'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ) 
    ),
    '50' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '55' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '60' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '8'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '5'
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
 ),
 'question' => array(
  'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous plus de sécurité à bord?',
  'info' => '',
  'Packs' => array(
   'PackMini' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack sécurité intérieur basique', 
    'c' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ), 
    'm' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ) 
   ),
   'PackTotal' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack sécurité interieur Complet', 
    '35' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '1'
     ) 
    ),
    '40' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '1'
     ) 
    ),
    '45' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '1'
     ) 
    ),
    '50' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ) 
    ),
    '55' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ) 
    ),
    '60' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '3'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '2'
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
 ),
 'question' => array(
  'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous plus de sécurité à l\'éxterieur?',
  'info' => '',
  'Packs' => array(
   'PackMini' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack sécurité éxterieur basique', 
    'c' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ), 
    'm' => array(
     'b7' => '1'
    ) 
   ),
   'PackTotal' => array(
    'description' => 'Pack sécurité éxterieur Complet', 
    '35' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '40' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '45' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '50' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '55' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    ),
    '60' => array(
     'c' => array(
      'b7' => '6'
     ), 
     'm' => array(
      'b7' => '4'
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
 )
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++){
 var_dump($questions['question']);
}


?>
```

I only get few last questions from my array and not the first :

```html
<?php

array(3) {
  ["designignation"]=>
  string(50) "Souhaitez-vous plus de sécurité à l'éxterieur?"
  ["info"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Packs"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["PackMini"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(34) "Pack sécurité éxterieur basique"
      ["c"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["b7"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      ["m"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["b7"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["PackTotal"]=>
    array(7) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(34) "Pack sécurité éxterieur Complet"
      [35]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [40]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [45]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [50]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [55]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [60]=>
      array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "6"
        }
        ["m"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["b7"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


 
  
  
    
   ?>
```

I just want to create an array and search informations inside to create my survey.

Thanks you for you helps.

Comment: first use echo'<pre>' ;print_r($questions); and all arrays avaible or not

Comment: `designignation` should be `designation` and "éxterieur" is spelled "extérieur" in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't have multiple times the same `question` key in your array. Each one, overrides the previous. That's why you get only one question (the last one).

You could format your array like this:

```
$questions = array(
    'question' => array(
        array(
            'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous pouvoir contrôler votre bateau ?',
            'info' => '',
            'Packs' => array(
            )
        ),
        array(
            'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous contrôler les lumières?',
            'info' => '',
            'Packs' => array(
            )
        ),
        array(
            'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous plus de confort à bord?',
            'info' => 'Mesure de tempêratires, humidité',
            'Packs' => array(
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

And use a `foreach()` to iterator over them:

```
foreach ($questions['question'] as $question) {
    var_dump($question);
}
```

Or:

```
$questions = array(
    array(
        'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous pouvoir contrôler votre bateau ?',
        'info' => '',
        'Packs' => array(
        )
    ),
    array(
        'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous contrôler les lumières?',
        'info' => '',
        'Packs' => array(
        )
    ),
    array(
        'designignation' => 'Souhaitez-vous plus de confort à bord?',
        'info' => 'Mesure de tempêratires, humidité',
        'Packs' => array(
        )
    ),
);
```

And the loop :

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    var_dump($question);
}
```

Comment: Oh right, thanks you Syscall toresolve my problem....  The problem was the format.